# Installing Linux on a Windows Computer Partition

Tags: linux, partitioning

I was thinking of setting up a partition on my Vista comp and installing Linux on that partition. I was gonna install Ubuntu on this partition. I was wondering if the equipment I have (i.e. video card, mouse, keyboard, network card) would be potentially unable to work on a linux platform? Any advice on doing this? I havent started yet, just doing my homework.

Thanks alot, any answer is always appreciated

Comment: Try superuser.com or ubuntu.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

You check the the ubuntu hardware compatibility link [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/switching/preparing-hardware.html).

Answer (score 1):

First try the Ubuntu live CD. If it your hardware works, go ahead and install. If your hardware doesn't work, you'll know what particular component causes trouble, and you can then enquire whether a bleeding-edge driver or obscure option can make it work.